# I have String of object I want to put this string in hash map in java

Tags: java, hashmap

I am creating DFA for this I am creating transition function object.
Acctualy transition table is give in string which I have puted below.
So I want to this `string` into an `hashMap`.

```
{"q1":{"0":"q2","1":"q1"},"q2":{"0":"q1","1":"q2"}}
```

Comment: please show what you have tried and tell us what is not working.

Answer (score 0):

Create a two maps as shown below

```
Map<String, String> innerObj = new HashMap<>();
Map<String, Map<String, String>> outerObj = new HashMap<>();
```

You can add objects like this

```
innerObj.put("0", "q2");
outerObj.put("q1", innerObj);
```

Comment: Thanks for your response but I want to put string in one shot